# How to do these redirections using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Two requirements...

```
domain.com/folder/file/
```

to

```
domain.com/folder/file.html
```

this one is slightly more complicated but i can live without it!

```
domain.com/folder/file/pagenumber/
```

to

```
domain.com/folder/file-pagenumber.html
```

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Do you currently have rules? Do you have a way to process URI's like `/folder/file/pagenumber/`?

Comment: This is for a vBulletin forum powered by vBseo. I made a mistake changing the core link structure in vBseo settings. I can revert back but this is what I am planning to stick to in the future. Google has been rather slow at updating the links. I was thinking putting in these rules in HTA for a couple of weeks till the new links are all properly indexed.

Handling page numbers is not that important for me. Rules for the first redirection would work just fine for me!

Comment: You want it to redirect the browser (301, URL in address bar changes) or just an internal rewrite?

Comment: For the user only. Internal links are managed by vBSEO. I am going to check the code provided by Matt S below. Seems to be just what I am looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the folders are always the same depth and there's always a trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/$ $1/$2.html [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/$ $1/$2-$3.html [L,R]
```